# How do you set handler mapping to a directory in IIS 6.0?

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

I have IIS 7.0 on my development machine and IIS 6.0 on my server.  On my development machine I was able to set a handler map on a directory within my site called /ViewHtml/ and I mapped it to asp.net. In my global.asax I check the request sent to asp.net for /ViewHtml/ and I serve the appropriate html file(html version of a Doc, Power Point, or Excel file) located outside this apps virtual directory. I am doing it this way because all files are permission protected, we didn't want to put these files in are database due to scalability, and I need to hide the path to these file on the server.  This all works in IIS 7.0 exactly how I would like it to.  Although I have not been able to get my IIS 6.0 server configured to map all requests to that directory to asp.net.

Any ideas?  Thanks Guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set up a web application using the same configuration you're using and I'm also getting the 404. I don't know why it works in IIS 7, but here's what I had to do to fix it.

Create a class that implements the System.Web.IHttpHandler class. move the the code from Application_BeginRequest to your implementation of IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest.

Now you just have to register your HTTP handler with ASP.NET. To do so add an entry in your Web.config at /configuration/system.web/httphandlers.

Web.config Example:

```
...
<httpHandlers>
    <clear />
    <add verb="*" path="*" type="namespace.classname, assemblyname" />
</httpHandlers>
...
```

That entry is telling ASP.NET to handle HTTP requests with any extension and any HTTP method by running the code in your HTTP hander. Note that I'm also clearing all the previously definded handlers (defined in the machine's web.config).

Note that you will still need the Application Mapping configured in IIS.

Comment: I did the exact similar thing as suggested above in the config. I am not really sure what needs to be added in Application mapping under Configuration? I added .html as one of the application extension with executable pointing to aspnet_isapi.dll of .net 2.0. Also there is nothing in global.asax. Still I get Page cannot be found. Can someone help.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly,  it sounds like you need add a "Wildcard Application Mapping" for your virtual directory. In other words, you want to forward all requests to any file extension to ASP.NET's ISAPI extension.

To do so, open the properties of your virtual directory. On the **Virtual Directory** tab (Home Directory tab if it's a web site), click the **Configuration...** button. Click the **Insert...** button next to the bottom list box in the dialog that shows up. In this dialog, choose "%SYSTEMROOT%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" as the executable and make sure to un-check "Verify that file exists" checkbox, since the files to be requested don't live in your virtual directory.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Matt.  I have tried this but I still get a 404 error when I try and show any pages through /ViewHtml/.  /ViewHtml/ is a virtual directory in my projects virtual directory, I added a wildcard application map from /ViewHtml/ to aspnet_isapi.dll (asp.net)  and  unchecked verify that file exists , then restarted IIS.  Did I miss something?

Comment: It sounds like you have everything right. Do you know if the code in your Global.asax file is running? Can you post a sample of the code in your Global.asax?

Comment: Thanks again for the quick response Matt.  I can post the code if you think it will help. Because of the 404 error I was under the impression that IIS is still handling the request and not mapping it to Asp.net where the golbal would handle it in Application_BeginRequest function.

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem is all about access policy , you have to make sure that the access policy is Read and not None , cz with None you have no permission to even read files from your website