# How to intercept a URL before hitting a website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have created a .dll for intercepting the cookie from the http request URL.
Placed it in the bin folder of the target website and added a module section in the web.config file.

I have a virtual directory in IIS for the same website. The virtual directory has some images which will be sent as a response for a particular URL.

The dll is not intercepting the URL for the virtual directory whereas the URL which is hitting the main website works fine.

Any solutions for interupting the URL pointing to the virtual directory too?

Comment: This is probably relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045227/how-do-you-set-handler-mapping-to-a-directory-in-iis-6-0

Comment: Your Virtual directory probably have its own config where <clear> tag is used in <modules> section